# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

When I console log locs.data I get an array, yet it says it is undefined..?  Not sure what's wrong with this.

```
let [locs, setLocs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/locations")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setLocs(data))
    }, [])
```

```
<Menu>
                        <MenuButton 
                            px={4}
                            py={2}
                            transition="all 0.2s"
                            borderRadius="md"
                            borderWidth="1px"
                            as={Button}
                            rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}>
                            Location Links
                        </MenuButton>
                        <MenuList>
                         {locs.data.map(loc => (
                            console.log(loc)
                         ))}
                        </MenuList>
                    </Menu>
```

Comment: `locs` starts off as an empty array. Arrays have no `.data` property. Maybe later when you fetch data it gets changed to something else, but that first render is just an empty array. Either change your initial value to have a `.data` property, or change your code so it can work if given an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printing runs before `useEffect` sometimes especially if you have async calls

try to check ifs it's defined *(true)*

```
let [locs, setLocs] = useState()
...
<MenuList>
  {locs?.data?.map(loc => ( // ? suffix means continue if true
    console.log(loc)
  ))}
</MenuList>
```

OR change default state value to

```
let [locs, setLocs] = useState({date:[]})
```

Comment: Looks like that was the issue.  I was not aware printing happened before the useEffect hook.  Thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your useEffect async :

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function myFunction() {
          let result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/locations");
          let json =  await result.json();
          setLocs(data);
        }

        myFunction();        
}, [])
```